# VPN connect only for some IP

Tags: vpn, android

I have Nexus 7 (2012) 4.4. I add VPN connection. It's successfull work.

But I want use VPN connection only to open some IP, for example: 192.168.139.177. All other + DNS I want use default wifi connectoin. Who I can todo this?

SOLUTION:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45403/how-to-forward-all-traffic-over-a-vpn-without-rooting-using-forwarding-routes

Comment: Since you have complete control over the VPN server configuration since you want to only allow an intranet address you will need to modify the configuration of the VPN server.

Comment: @Ramhound, no I don't have. I have only vpn-host and login/password.

Comment: If you don't have the ability to configure the VPN server then you will unable to only allow certain intranet ip addresses.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45403/how-to-forward-all-traffic-over-a-vpn-without-rooting-using-forwarding-routes